# How can I update a row in polars?

Tags: python, python-polars

I haven't found anything as to how to actually update a row, so what I've been doing (to update the last row, for example) is `df.slice(0, -1).vstack(single_row_df)`.

Is there a better or more efficient way to do this?

Comment: You could use (pl.when)[https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.when.html#polars.when] to do `pl.when(<condition for row I want to change>)` and change the relevant columns by wrapping all columns in a `pl.when`. If that is more efficient, not sure. I do know that this is an anti-pattern, and in most cases there is no real need to be able to do this.

Comment: I have to say, both approaches seem unintuitive to me. Stacking multiple `pl.when` sounds inefficient, especially the more columns you have. I'll stick to what I have for now but I'll keep that in mind. Thanks.

Comment: It is difficult to comment on the relative efficiencies between the two approaches when you're not detailing how you're creating `single_row_df` and it seems unlikely that it's always the last row (ie `slice(0,-1)`) that you'd want to update.